# Spring MVC : Mapping an input button (non submit) with the controller request

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, request

I'm trying to map a button action to the controller function.
When I tried with :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void processValidateGenerate 
....
```

and

```
<input type="button" id="continue" name="continue"...>
```

that works just fine, but now i want to add another button, so to differentiate betweent them I added so for the first action :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="continue")
public void processValidateGenerate 
....
```

but the function is not called anymore when the button is pressed, I think that works only for a submit input.

Are there any solution to do this with a non submit input ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript/jquery to do an ajax call and hit the required controller method.

```
function doSomething(){
$.ajax({                                  //This is a jquery ajax call. You need to inlude jquery js files to do
type: "POST",                              // this operation
url: //URL,
data: //JSON data
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Operation done: " + msg );
window.location.href=contextPath+"/newURL";      //If you want to go to a new page
});
}
```

now add the new button (It doesn't matter even it isn't a button, a div would suffice). Use the onclick function and give the javscript function name.

```
<input type="button" id="newcontinuebutton" name="continue" onclick=doSomething()...>
```

You can check the jquery ajax details [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

I think this would help you.